# JSch not closing sshd

Tags: sftp, jsch

Has anyone seen where JSch leaves sshd sessions open?

I've got a java client which performs regular SFTP connections (it polls every one hour) and it seems to  leave behind a sshd session. These eventually build up over time and causes us to have a **"too many files open"** exception in the OS (it hits the limit per process(1024) for those who are interested).

In my client I close the SFTPChannel, then the Channel (redundant really as closing the SFTPChannel closes the Channel) and lastly the Session, so I'm pretty sure I'm cleaning up correctly (and I can see I have a 'disconnect' for each 'connect', so they do marry up)

Comment: This looks like a bug, but I'm not sure where. What is your JSch version? What is your client and server OS? What is your SSHD (including version)?

Comment: Some days ago I've read a report of the same issue with JSch 1.44 and an Solaris Sshd.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [a mail thread of jsch-users ML](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=201204171342.WAA29210@jcraft.com&forum_name=jsch-users),

That problem has been caused by a bug in older OpenSSH's sshd.
The recent OpenSSH has fixed it.

Comment: Just to repeat what that thread says, Open SSH 5.3 doesn't have the issue whereas 4.7 did. So somewhere in that version range it got fixed.