# JSch port closing

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to porgram a ssh tunneling program but it seems that the port which are not in use any longer are still not available.
An example for the structure of my tunnels:

First tunnel: Local Port -> 22, Local-IP: 1.2.3.4, user..., pw..., tunnelport -> 5000

Next tunnel: Local Port -> 5000, Local-IP: localhost, user..., pw.., tunnelport -> 5001

Next tunnel: Local Port -> 5001, Local-IP: localhost, user..., pw.., tunnelport -> 5002

So far so good.
Now here is the code with which I try to close all the tunnels:

```
private void sortiiii(Map<Session, Integer> sessions) throws JSchException{
    Map<Session, Integer> map = sessions;
    ValueComparator bvc = new ValueComparator(map);
    TreeMap<Session, Integer> sorted_map = new TreeMap(bvc);

    sorted_map.putAll(map);
    for (Session key : sorted_map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(sorted_map.get(key));
        String [] alle = key.getPortForwardingL();
        for (int i=0; i<alle.length; ++i){
            System.out.println(alle[i]);
        }


        key.delPortForwardingL(sorted_map.get(key));
        key.disconnect();
    }
}
```

The map is sorted because one tunnel needs the one before and so on...

Can anybody imagine why port 5000, 5001, 5002... are not available after i am cleaning the connections?

Comment: Maybe this will help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398634/jsch-not-closing-sshd?rq=1