# SSH sessions not closing after sftp transfer

Tags: java, linux, session, ssh

Java code transfers (SFTP) files from local to remote server every 15 mins.
Both are linux servers with below configs:

```
user# ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
user# uname -a
Linux serverName 2.6.39-400.24.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 11:46:52 PDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The issue is, for some reason, the ssh sessions on remote server donot seem to close. 
They just build up until the max. no. of processes breaches and then pipe broken error occurs when trying to login.

The sessions and channels have been definitely closed in the Java code using channel.disconnect() and session.disconnect(). There are no errors in the java code.

Also, why is that there are three processes running for a single file (sftp transfer).

```
root     63340  2932  0 12:10 ?        00:00:00 sshd: user [priv]
user     63346 63340  0 12:10 ?        00:00:00 sshd: user@notty
user     63347 63346  0 12:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Can someone please help with any info/tip regarding this issue?

Checked a similar thread but not exactly the same - [JSch not closing sshd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398634/jsch-not-closing-sshd)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the java code which is launching these SFTP sessions?

Comment: When you kill the java process is the problem gone? I am quite sure it is a Java problem (especially if killing the program helps).